# Check String contain all elements in list using Linq and case insensitive

Tags: c#, linq, case-insensitive

I want to write a function that filter files in directory. The method received path, list of tokens the file must be contain and list of token that should not be in the file.

my code is like this:

```
private String[] enumerateFilesByFilter(String path, List<String> contain, List<String> notContain)
{
    String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(f => (contain.All(f.Contains)) && (!notContain.Any(f.Contains))).ToArray();
    //String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(f => f.IndexOf(contain.All(f.Contains), 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1).ToArray();
    return files;
}
```

I try to receive list of files that match the criteria and I succeed to obtain correct list but just for sensitive tokens.

(In the commend you can see my try to get one for case insensitive but there is an error...)

How can I check if the filename contain all string in the list in case insensitive ?

### Edit

Here's an example. Let's say I have the follow files in my directory:

> proj_debug_3.2.0.txt
>
> proj_release_3.2.1.txt
>
> proj_release_3.2.1_useThis_TRY.txt
>
> proj_release_3.2.1_UseThis.txt

so call to

```
enumerateFilesByFilter(path, new List<String> { "Release", "useThis" }, new List<String> {"try", "debug" });
```

should return `proj_release_3.2.1_UseThis.txt` file

Comment: Fyi, use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead of `Directory.GetFiles` if you use `Where` since it can start processing before all files are returned as opposed to GetFiles which first creates an array of all files.

Comment: Can a file be both in contain and not contain at the same time?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, no. contain list is different from notContain...

Comment: If a file isn't in not contain, is it definitely in contain or there is no such guarantee?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I'm not care here about user mistakes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I'd define a new extension method for case-insensitive search:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string source, string pattern, StringComparison comparision)
    {
        return source.IndexOf(pattern, comparision) >= 0;
    }
}
```

Then rewrite your method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFilesByFilter(String path, List<String> include, List<String> exclude)
    {
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).
            Where(f => include.All(i => f.Contains(i, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).
            Where(f => exclude.All(i => !f.Contains(i, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
    }
```

Please note, that I used IEnumerable as return type and Directory.EnumerateFiles() for the file system listing. This way the whole operation is much more efficient, and using only enumerables.

Comment: thanks, but you have an error on `f => include.All` line

Comment: What do you mean by "you have an error"?

I tried it with your example above, it compiles and gives the correct result.

Comment: You're right, I put `StringExtensions` class in the wrong place. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

This should work as desired:

```
private String[] enumerateFilesByFilter(String path, List<String> contain, List<String> notContain)
{
    String[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
        .Where(f => contain.All(s => s.IndexOf(f, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
             && !notContain.Any(s => s.IndexOf(f, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
        .ToArray();
    return files;
}
```

Note that i use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead of `Directory.GetFiles` because it can start processing before all files are returned as opposed to `GetFiles` which first creates an array of all files.

Maybe you should also consider to use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)` to check only the file-name instead of the full path.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I received an empty array... (and it's not happen when I using my command `String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(f => (contain.All(f.Contains)) && (!notContain.Any(f.Contains))).ToArray();`

Comment: @AsfK: maybe because the `notContain.Any` now works case insensitive and that filters more than before. Difficult to help without sample data which deomstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution (the solution is ugly but working):

```
private String[] enumerateFilesByFilter(String path, List<String> contain, List<String> notContain)
{
    String[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Where(f => (contain.All(c => f.ToLower().Contains(c.ToLower()))) &&
        (!notContain.Any(c => f.ToLower().Contains(c.ToLower())) )).ToArray();
    return files;
}
```